# How to install Nitrux using znx and dual-boot with it Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot

I want to install Nitrux, which can be "deployed" using znx, and dual-boot it with Windows 10. But I don't know how to begin with this.

Are you required to make a partition? How do you use znx to have a dual boot?

Comment: Use a virtual machine like VirtualBox, which is free. The fact you are asking this question in this way would be a strong indicator that you should probably learn more, in a risk free way, about GNU/Linux before trying to start with a multiboot setup. The usual outcome when a new user tries to create a multiboot environment is that they lose the ability to boot into windows, either right away, or after an update. Or they lose the ability to boot into Linux after a windows update. Easy problems to fix if you know how, but start easy and just run linux in a vm. The distro doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: The information below is exclusively for the ISO images that include or support znx and does not pertain to the ISO files that use a traditional installer such as Calamares.**

---

Hypothetically yes, you could dual-boot Windows 10 and Nitrux if you deployed Nitrux with znx. However, we haven't tested this scenario. Both Windows 10 and Linux can use a shared ESP (EFI System Partition), and Windows can access Btrfs partitions using [this third-party driver](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs).

Adding the boot loader file (bootx64.efi), GRUB configuration file (grub.cfg), and theme directory (themes) from the znx AppImage to the ESP and adding an EFI boot entry (not a GRUB entry) to point to the boot loader allow you to boot the ISO images.

Then you need to create a Btrfs partition to *deploy* the ISO files using znx and store the user data when you boot to Nitrux and change the labels from the ESP and the Btrfs partitions to `ZNX_BOOT` and `ZNX_DATA`, respectively.

Finally, you need to add an EFI boot entry that points to the boot loader file in the ESP. By using the EFI, you can bypass the need for any Windows BOot Manager-GRUB mishaps.

However, you wouldn't be able to deploy ISO images from Windows, not only because WSL in Windows 10 doesn't include a FUSE module and the AppImage wouldn't run, WSL can't access block devices.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from FAQ on Nitrux: It is not possible to deploy Nitux from a windows machine but you can create a linux live USB to install Nitrux.

> [Deploying Nitrux from Windows](https://nxos.org/en/faq/#deploy-nitrux-from-windows)
>
> Unfortunately for Windows users, the AppImage of znx does not run in WSL or Cygwin because neither can access the block devices in a computer and the kernel used by WSL does not have the FUSE module included which is a massive problem and one problem that znx cannot fix since it isn’t a problem of znx but a problem with Windows not being a POSIX system.
>
> To summarize, **we acknowledge that for Windows users this is not ideal as it requires adding two more steps to the process. If you are coming from Windows, please follow this workflow.**
>
> 1)  Download a minimal conventional Linux distribution, for example, [Fedora Server Net-install](https://getfedora.org/es/server/download/), [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) or any other Linux distribution that you want; you need something where the AppImage can run and that it provides you of network access.
>
> 2) Create a Live USB of that distribution and boot from it.
>
> Please note that:
>
> You do not need to use a full desktop Linux system to complete the deployment at any point.
>
> You only need to meet two requirements: To run a Linux with FUSE included and have network access.

Comment: Run it with --appimage-extract-and-run, then it does not need FUSE.